# Filebeat logs stored in /tmp are causing pod eviction

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, elastic-stack, filebeat

i am seeing an issue on my environment which is using filebeat for logging and monitoring where files with large amounts of storage used are getting created. I presume these are log files created by filebeat and these files are getting stored in my pods /tmp directory. I am using openshift 4.11.9 with kubernetes 1.24.

```
total 680892
-rw-r--r--. 1 1000680000 1000680000 45518518 Mar  7 01:35 monitoring-stdout---supervisor-jti9vqc6.log
-rw-r-----. 1 1000680000 1000680000  5803121 Mar  7 01:35 pch4543779432628550477.history.gz
-rw-r-----. 1 1000680000 1000680000 54381482 Mar  7 01:35 pch4543779432628550477.history
-rw-r-----. 1 1000680000 1000680000  2185531 Mar  7 01:35 pch6805951925590054337.history
drwxrwsrwx. 4 root       1000680000     4096 Mar  7 01:28 .
-rw-r--r--. 1 1000680000 1000680000 52428996 Mar  7 01:28 monitoring-stdout---supervisor-jti9vqc6.log.1
-rw-r-----. 1 1000680000 1000680000    72101 Mar  7 01:26 pch6805951925590054337.history.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 1000680000 1000680000 52428802 Mar  7 01:20 monitoring-stdout---supervisor-jti9vqc6.log.2
-rw-r--r--. 1 1000680000 1000680000 52428984 Mar  7 01:12 monitoring-stdout---supervisor-jti9vqc6.log.3
-rw-r--r--. 1 1000680000 1000680000 52428907 Mar  7 01:04 monitoring-stdout---supervisor-jti9vqc6.log.4
-rw-r--r--. 1 1000680000 1000680000 52429189 Mar  7 00:55 monitoring-stdout---supervisor-jti9vqc6.log.5
-rw-r--r--. 1 1000680000 1000680000 52428807 Mar  7 00:47 monitoring-stdout---supervisor-jti9vqc6.log.6
-rw-r--r--. 1 1000680000 1000680000 52428867 Mar  7 00:39 monitoring-stdout---supervisor-jti9vqc6.log.7
-rw-r--r--. 1 1000680000 1000680000 52429055 Mar  7 00:31 monitoring-stdout---supervisor-jti9vqc6.log.8
-rw-r--r--. 1 1000680000 1000680000 52428920 Mar  7 00:23 monitoring-stdout---supervisor-jti9vqc6.log.9
-rw-r--r--. 1 1000680000 1000680000 52428974 Mar  7 00:15 monitoring-stdout---supervisor-jti9vqc6.log.10
-rw-r-----. 1 1000680000 1000680000   173586 Mar  6 23:41 pch783860385935287176.history.gz
-rw-r-----. 1 1000680000 1000680000 11674655 Mar  6 23:41 pch7390231010312236403.history.gz
drwxr-s---. 2 1000680000 1000680000     4096 Mar  6 19:41 axis2-tmp-597419792942874660.tmp
-rw-r-----. 1 1000680000 1000680000        0 Mar  6 19:41 axis2-tmp-597419792942874660.tmp.lck
drwxrwxrwt. 4 1000680000 root             64 Mar  6 19:40 .com_ibm_tools_attach
-rw-------. 1 1000680000 1000680000        0 Mar  6 19:39 filebeat-syslog-stderr---supervisor-j80_3v5j.log
-rw-------. 1 1000680000 1000680000        0 Mar  6 19:39 filebeat-syslog-stdout---supervisor-hq39mt_v.log
-rw-------. 1 1000680000 1000680000        0 Mar  6 19:39 filebeat-was-stderr---supervisor-en73_cgc.log
-rw-------. 1 1000680000 1000680000        0 Mar  6 19:39 filebeat-was-stdout---supervisor-v0comu9p.log
-rw-------. 1 1000680000 1000680000        0 Mar  6 19:39 filebeat-cpe-stderr---supervisor-v8837rxx.log
-rw-------. 1 1000680000 1000680000        0 Mar  6 19:39 filebeat-cpe-stdout---supervisor-_0l469zf.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 1000680000 1000680000        3 Mar  6 19:39 supervisord.pid
srwx------. 1 1000680000 1000680000        0 Mar  6 19:39 supervisor.sock
dr-xr-xr-x. 1 root       root             28 Mar  6 19:39 ..
```

As you can see these are the files being created and its the files starting from monitoring-*.log that i am concerned about.
i was wondering if there were any solutions that could be provided to any of the following points

Reduce the file size
change the directory from /tmp to some other directory
Reduce the amount of time these files take to wrap the content around each other.
any thoughts on this would be gladly appreciated

I have tried to find out why the files are being sent to /tmp and unable to find a way to modify the output directory or figure out how to reduce the number of files generated

Answer (score 0):

In OpenShift/Kubernetes, there is a size limit for each running container. So if the application inside your container is generating very large log files, the container will be killed when it exceeds that size limit.

### EmptyDir

One possible solution is to use an `EmptyDir` volume and mount it at the log file location, which you believe is `/tmp`.

```
$ oc set volume dc/<name> --add --name=logs --type=emptydir --mount-path=/tmp
```

Just keep in mind that,

> `emptyDir` volume storage may be restricted by a quota based on the pod’s FSGroup, if the FSGroup parameter is enabled by your cluster administrator.

[Reference](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.11/nodes/containers/nodes-containers-volumes.html)

### Increase Overlay Size

Another solution is to increase the maximum Overlay size using a `ContainerRuntimeConfig` CRD. However, this configuration will apply to all containers running on the nodes that match the label selector, not just your application.

*overlaysize.yml*:

```yaml
apiVersion: machineconfiguration.openshift.io/v1
kind: ContainerRuntimeConfig
metadata:
 name: overlay-size
spec:
 machineConfigPoolSelector:
   matchLabels:
     custom-crio: overlay-size
 containerRuntimeConfig:
   pidsLimit: 2048
   logLevel: debug
   overlaySize: 8G
```

*Apply the configuration changes*:

```
$ oc apply -f overlaysize.yml
$ oc edit machineconfigpool worker
```

*Update Worker Config*:

```yaml
apiVersion: machineconfiguration.openshift.io/v1
kind: MachineConfigPool
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2020-07-09T15:46:34Z"
  generation: 3
  labels:
    custom-crio: overlay-size
    machineconfiguration.openshift.io/mco-built-in: ""
```

[Reference 1](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.11/post_installation_configuration/machine-configuration-tasks.html#set-the-default-max-container-root-partition-size-for-overlay-with-crio_post-install-machine-configuration-tasks), [Reference 2](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/5216861)